# save vbscript to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have a batch file that contain:

```
@echo off

start telnet x.x.x.x 5000
cscript script_test.vbs
```

while script_test.vbs contains:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 50 

'Enter username
OBJECT.SendKeys "xxxx{ENTER}" 
'Enter password
WScript.sleep 1000
OBJECT.SendKeys"xxxx{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 1000
'First Command
OBJECT.SendKeys"COMMAND1 {ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 100

OBJECT.SendKeys " "
```

Noting that COMMAND1 will result an output that I need to save in a file.

How to save the output resulting from this command to a specific file by specifying its path.

Comment: [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `SendKeys` for automating the `telnet` command that ships with Windows. Use a `telnet` command that is actually scriptable, like [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

```
plink -batch -telnet -l USERNAME -pw PASSWORD x.x.x.x COMMAND1
```

Comment: I think telnet connection cannot be automated with plink. Besides that , I'm logging in to a host that needs a specific format while entering the credentials , so a standard username and password wont work.
On the other hand , why not to use Sendkeys in such way ? what is the issue ?

Comment: The main issue is that `SendKeys` sends the keystrokes to the foreground window. Whatever that is. So if something pops into the foreground while your VBScript is typing, the keystrokes go to an undesired location. Do not use `SendKeys` unless you triple-checked that no other option is available.

Comment: can you suggest another way to do it ?

Comment: I believe I already did. If for some reason you must rely on sending keystrokes you may want to take a look at [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: please "Ansgar" help me i don't know where i complain there is guy have multi account keep down vote everyday with no reason he have no idea of programming or system engineer as you moderator in this community please and professional engineer check my post and judge me and him because he do that everyday after i uncover him that he din't know vbscript and he don't know what is the instance the problem he is one of the top vbscript all time.thanks you in advance.sallam.

Comment: @hollopost SO has a rather good detection for serial downvoting, and detected serial down (or up-)votes are automatically rolled back. However, if you feel someone's specifically targeting you're answers and evaded that detection mechanisms you can flag one of your downvoted answers as "in need of moderator intervention" and explain (as detailed as possible) why you feel you're being the target of serial/sock-puppet downvotes. You can also talk to moderators in chat somewhere I think. For more general questions please use [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @hollopost With that said, the answers you posted on this question simply aren't good, and one of the downvotes on each of them is from me. From what I can see they don't address the OP's problem. Both your answers assume that the telnet server is running on a Windows system, which from what the OP mentioned in their question and comments does not seem to be the case.

Comment: my script is written to run form windows xp service pack 2 to another xp or window 7 and have no problem of that.and i was about to write another script run from window 7 to win7 or xp and the person  ask the question didn't complain form first answer about the system he complain of remote telnet can't read %temp% that all and he as me solution and i replay .so why they downvote me it the person didn't complain again of the system.

Comment: ask you "Ansgar" to check my  first post then my post was different and he just using his multi account to downvote my post and when i told him that he is not engineer or programmer because he can't understand what is different between process by name and process commandline .he keep downvote my post the he delete it and its easy for hem have multi .please go and check my first post that he delete and all comment  he delete to cover him self after i send message to moderator but they didn't do anything.

Comment: and again when i post second question do the same game with me downvote my post with no reason .go and check his post there he didn't know when you use xml http request and loading full page .and keep downvote every day